# Not able to upgrade pycairo in Python3

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade pycairo package but getting following error:

```
$ python3 -m pip install -U pycairo 
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached pycairo-1.19.1.tar.gz (205 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycairo
    Running setup.py install for pycairo ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ho1du2qw/pycairo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ho1du2qw/pycairo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-21711no1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/abcde/.local/include/python3.7m/pycairo
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ho1du2qw/pycairo/
    Complete output (19 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cairo
    copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cairo
    copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cairo
    copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cairo
    running build_ext
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cairo
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=19 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c cairo/device.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cairo/device.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
    cairo/device.c:30:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ho1du2qw/pycairo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ho1du2qw/pycairo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-21711no1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/abcde/.local/include/python3.7m/pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: file `Python.h` means you have to install `python-dev` with C/C++ headers `.h` because it has to compile some C/C++ code. On Linux Mint/Ubuntu/Debian it could be `apt install python-dev` or `apt install python3-dev` eventually `apt install python3.7-dev`

Comment: Yes, it worked. If you enter this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File `Python.h` means you have to install `python-dev` with C/C++ headers `.h` because it has to compile some C/C++ code.

On Linux Mint/Ubuntu/Debian it could be one of this command

```
apt install python-dev
apt install python3-dev
apt install python3.7-dev
```